Style Code with highlightJS inside a web component
I have a web component with a <pre><code>... section which I would like styled by an external stylesheet (highlightJS).
NOTE: My Web Component has a slot and the pre and code blocks are inserted programmatically.

If I include the style once globally it does not target the shadow dom of my component

This is by design as components are encapsulated
I don't really want to mess with the source CSS though I am willing to extend it



If I include the style inside my template (see below) I supposed it will load the stylesheet once for each instance. According to the network tab however it is only loaded once. Is this good practice?
Is there a way to allow my web component's <code> blocks to be styled by external stylesheets?



If I include the style inside my template (see below) I supposed it
will load the stylesheet once for each instance. According to the
network tab however it is only loaded once. Is this good practice?

A URI is a URI is a URI, and if you have not disabled caching, a URI will only be loaded once.
For a Stylesheet to work inside shadowDOM you do need to link it inside shadowDOM.
There is also adoptedStyleSheets you can use, depending on your use-case.

Is there a way to allow my web component's  blocks to be styled
by external stylesheets?

HighlightJS comes with loads of Themes:
https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/tree/main/src/styles
Overriding HighlightJS CSS can be done, its just one CSS file to edit
You might not need HighlightJS, it can be done with one very cool font-file only
https://blog.glyphdrawing.club/font-with-built-in-syntax-highlighting/

That font is wild yo!

Now all we need is find someone who does a <styled-textarea> Web Component, with lineNumbers and line highlightinng for (Web Component) educational purposes

Your answer is correct and I'd like to accept it but with a working example of adoptedStyleSheets. Shall I edit your reply or will you?

Feel free to edit it, tnx
